# What benefits would the U.S. gain from voting against A/HRC/51/L.28 Rev.1?

Tags: united-states, united-nations, racism

https://twitter.com/UN_HRC/status/1578407316583497729

> #HRC51 | Draft resolution A/HRC/51/L.28 Rev.1: “From rhetoric to reality: a global call for concrete action against #racism, racial
> discrimination, xenophobia and related intolerance” was ADOPTED.

What benefits would the U.S. gain from voting against A/HRC/51/L.28 Rev.1?

https://documents-dds-ny.un.org/doc/UNDOC/GEN/G17/294/26/PDF/G1729426.pdf?OpenElement

> Emphasizing the primacy of the International Convention on the
> Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination as a principal
> international instrument to combat all the scourges of racism, and in
> this regard noting with concern that the commitment made at the World
> Conference against Racism, Racial Discrimination, Xenophobia and
> Related Intolerance to achieve universal ratification of this primary
> instrument by 2005 was regrettably not fulfilled, and underlining the
> imperative need to elaborate complementary international standards as
> instructed by paragraph 199 of the Durban Declaration and Programme of
> Action

So it seems like it's just calls for the end of racism and racial discrimination, but for some reason the United States voted against it. Doesn't the U.S. have more to gain from eliminating racism, if so, then what does the United States have to gain from voting against such a measure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This resolution comes up time and time again
https://digitallibrary.un.org/search?ln=en&p=From+rhetoric+to+reality%3A+a+global+call+for+concrete+action+against+racism&f=&action_search=Search

The US has explained it's vote against before:
https://usun.usmission.gov/explanation-of-vote-for-the-a-global-call-for-concrete-action-for-the-elimination-of-racism-racial-discrimination-xenophobia-and-related-intolerance/

The US State department opinion is that this proposal is weak, violates free speech rights, and compels the US (and others) to pay reparations unfairly.

Comment: The DDPA which is mentioned in the last para of that seems to equate Zionism with racism, according to its critics https://www.cairn.info/revue-internationale-de-droit-penal-2002-1-page-301.htm

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durban_III was then boycotted by more countries, including some from the EU.

Answer (score 4):

The (2021 version of the) resolution, A/HRC/RES/48/18, mentions "Durban" 33 times. The [Durban conferences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durban_III) have an increasingly bad rep in "the West", with major European countries (France, Germany, and the UK) boycotting the later ones as well. ([According](https://www.al-monitor.com/originals/2021/09/israel-marks-diplomatic-victory-33-countries-boycott-durban-iv-conference) to US & Israeli sources, the number of countries boycotting "Durban IV", which was actually held in NY, was >twice that for "Durban III", i.e. 30+ vs 15.) I gather the Western objections are due to the Palestinian cause being turned into a platform for anti-semitism in those venues.

That's reflected in the vote record for that resolution in the Human Rights Council on 11 October 2021:

> Adopted by a recorded vote of 32 to 10, with 5 abstentions.
>
> In favour: Argentina, Armenia, Bahamas, Bahrain, Bangladesh, Bolivia (Plurinational State of), Brazil, Burkina Faso, Cameroon, China, Côte d’Ivoire, Cuba, Eritrea, Fiji, Gabon, India, Indonesia, Libya, Malawi, Mauritania, Mexico, Namibia, Nepal, Pakistan, Philippines, Russian Federation, Senegal, Somalia, Sudan, Togo, Uzbekistan and Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)
>
> Against: Austria, Czechia, Denmark, France, Germany, Italy, Netherlands, Poland, Ukraine and United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland
>
> Abstaining:
> Bulgaria, Japan, Marshall Islands, Republic of Korea and Uruguay

The 2022 version (A/HRC/51/L.28/Rev.1) was introduced as "Chile, Côte d’Ivoire, Pakistan: draft resolution". It is a slightly longer than the 2021 version (9 pages vs 6 pages). It mentions "Durban" 38 times. It is somewhat hard to discern the exact additions, because some paragraphs were swizzled around. Both editions ask for more UN commemorations of the 20th anniversary of the DDPA. The 2022 version additionally asks for some UN brochures to include it, and some kind of integration of the DDPA commemorations with those for the [UDHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Declaration_of_Human_Rights) and those for the [VDPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_Declaration_and_Programme_of_Action) (paras 36, 38).

The voting record paints roughly the same picture though:

> In favour (32): Argentina, Armenia, Benin, Bolivia, Brazil, Cameroon, China, Cote d’Ivoire, Cuba, Eritrea, Gabon, Gambia, Honduras, India, Indonesia, Kazakhstan, Libya, Malawi, Malaysia, Mauritania, Mexico, Namibia, Nepal, Pakistan, Paraguay, Qatar, Senegal, Somalia, Sudan, United Arab Emirates and Venezuela.
>
> Against (9): Czechia, France, Germany, Montenegro, Netherlands, Poland, Ukraine, United Kingdom and United States.
>
> Abstentions (6): Finland, Japan, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Marshall Islands, Republic of Korea and Uzbekistan.

Comment: *For the 2022 version, I could only find the voting record* The text format is at item  [Action on Resolution under Agenda Item Nine on Racism ...](https://www.ohchr.org/en/press-releases/2022/10/human-rights-council-adopts-14-resolutions-extends-mandates-ethiopia-burundi), 07 October 2022.

Comment: @RickSmith: that can't be the full text. The 2021 version was 7 pages long. So that's only a one-para summary you found for 2022. (It is followed by the text version of the voting record though.)

Answer (score 2):

**Because it [endorses](https://usun.usmission.gov/explanation-of-vote-for-the-a-global-call-for-concrete-action-for-the-elimination-of-racism-racial-discrimination-xenophobia-and-related-intolerance/) Durban Declaration and Program of Action**.

USA has [concerns](https://geneva.usmission.gov/2011/09/27/durban-declaration-and-programme-of-action/) about this program, including its unfair and unacceptable singling out of Israel and endorsement of overbroad restrictions on freedom of expression that run counter to the U.S. commitment to robust free speech.

[Durban Declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Conference_against_Racism) is somewhat controversial:

- During 2001 review, Canada, followed by the U.S. and Israel walked out midway through the conference over a draft resolution that, in their opinion, singled out Israel for criticism and likened Zionism to racism. Also, African countries, led by Nigeria and Zimbabwe, wanted apologies from each of the countries responsible for slavery, recognition of it as a crime against humanity, and reparations called as such.
- During 2009 year review, about 40 delegates walked out during Iranian president Mahmoud Ahmadinejad's speech after he described Israel as a "racist government" and questioned the creation of the state of Israel.
- The 2021 year conference was blocked by many countries, including Albania, Australia, Austria, Bulgaria, Canada, Colombia, Croatia, Cyprus, Czech Republic, Denmark, Dominican Republic, Estonia, France, Georgia, Germany, Greece, Honduras, Hungary, Israel, Italy, Latvia, Lithuania, Montenegro, Moldova, Netherlands, New Zealand, North Macedonia, Poland, Romania, Serbia, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Ukraine, United Kingdom, United States and Uruguay.

Hence may be explainable.